# Using rendercomplete for vector layer in OpenLayers 5

Tags: openlayers

I am interested to add a preloader on the web page, cause i'm loading on the map a 15mb vector, so when all layers are loaded on the map i will hide the preloader.

I have found the `rendercomplete` function in the [API docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_render_Event-RenderEvent.html#event:rendercomplete), how can i implement this?

something like

```
map.rendercomplete(function(){
//...
})
```

Vector:

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'getjson.json',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),style:style_simple
});
```

Map:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [roadlayer,vector],
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([new ol.control.ScaleLine()]),
    view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.33386, 35.14710]),
    zoom: 14,
    maxZoom: 19
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you add your vector layer definition code to your question? This will help finding the right answer.

Comment: added the vector which is loaded on the map

Comment: In this case my answer below should be OK.

Comment: @TomazicM okay will check on Monday and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleanest solution seems to be to test the state of vector source with `getState()` method. When source data is loaded, it returns `ready` value.

If vector layer is GeoJSON, implementation could look something like this:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'myGeojSON_file.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: style
});

var sourceEventListener = vectorSource.on('change', function(e) {
  if (vectorSource.getState() == 'ready') {
    console.log('GeoJSON loaded');
    vectorSource.un('change', sourceEventListener);
  }
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Comment: it seems that browsers cache the Json file and sometimes this method cannot hide the preloader

Comment: A vector source can also emit featuresloadend when all features have been added. However it depends on if the loader for that source calls the callback when finished.

Answer (score 4):

Catching events is pretty straightforward:

```
map.on('rendercomplete', e => {
    // do something

})
```

Depending on your approach you need to hide the loader. If it's a Single Page Application you change the state. If it's a plain JS script you can remove the loader node from the DOM like 
`var el = document.getElementById('loader'); 
if (el){el.remove()}`

Comment: i log the event and it executes 96 times, sometimes 94,95,etc. Not sure if it works with vector layers as it executes immediately when base tile layer is loaded

Comment: From api docs: “Triggered when rendering is complete, i.e. all sources and tiles have finished loading for the current viewport, and all tiles are faded in.”

Comment: yes but i am trying to detect vector load not tile. Vector loads 15 mb, tile is way less

Comment: The Layer class triggers the same event. Just use layer.on(...)

Comment: the event is triggered before the json in the vector layer is downloaded

Comment: @dmh126 I don't think the layer object will trigger 'rendercomplete', only the map object.